# Browser Extension pop-up when I access a particular URL

Tags: html, json, google-chrome-extension, browser, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Browser extension. Almost completed the project.

But,

1. **I want that extension to pop-up automatically (without clicking the icon), when I access a particular website in a browser**
2. **And I want to make the pop-up page visible on the tab until I close the tab.**

I have no idea on how to do this.

It would be helpful, if any of you guys share your ideas!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For first point you should intercept the navigation url by setting a handler for chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded event
and then open the popup with chrome.action.openPopup() (it might not work on some 107 version subversion).
For 2nd point there is no chance

Comment: Add your UI into the web page e.g. inside iframe exposed via `web_accessible_resources`.

Comment: It seems that what you're trying to achieve isn't possible with the popup, but could be done with a Content Script instead. Have you considered using content scripts? https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/